# Many want to be me

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> Many want to be me
>
> If you hit your head
>
> you'll see me
>
> If you "begin" but don't get Ted
>
> That's the way to reveal me

What am I?

Comment: Sam Bee!  no that can't be right.

Comment: If I got the correct answer, please click the gray check under my answer to accept it and mark this puzzle solved... and give me more rep :P

Answer (score 12):

> A star

Many want to be me

> Everyone wants to be a star, like a celebrity

If you hit your head you'll see me

> you'll see stars when you hit your head

If you "begin" but don't get Ted That's the way to reveal me

> <s>not sure</s> StarTED. If you take away 'TED' it's 'star'. *(Thanks, @Sid!)*

Comment: Last line for StarTED?